# Optimizing image thresholding in OpenCV (reimplementation of Otsu)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've been working on an image thresholding technique inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/image-thresholding-from-scratch-a66ae0fb6f09) on image thresholding. The goal is to find the best threshold value for binarizing images. This approach involves calculating a criterion for each possible threshold and selecting the one that minimizes this criterion. This is akin to Otsu's method but implemented manually to provide more control and potentially adapt to specific requirements.

I tried several other ways like:

```
cv::threshold(im_gray, img_bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

but only this approach was always able to find the best threshold in each case. However, it is very slow without resizing the input image. The performance issue stem from the exhaustive calculation for each threshold value across the entire image, which becomes computationally expensive for larger images.

Here is the code so far:

```
double CalculateCriteria(const cv::Mat& im, int th) {
    cv::Mat thresholdedIm = cv::Mat::zeros(im.size(), CV_64F);
    thresholdedIm.setTo(1, im >= th);

    double nbPixels = im.total();
    double nbPixels1 = cv::countNonZero(thresholdedIm);
    double weight1 = nbPixels1 / nbPixels;
    double weight0 = 1 - weight1;

    if (weight1 == 0 || weight0 == 0) {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    }

    cv::Mat valPixels1, valPixels0;
    im.copyTo(valPixels1, thresholdedIm == 1);
    im.copyTo(valPixels0, thresholdedIm == 0);

    cv::Scalar mean1, stdDev1, mean0, stdDev0;
    cv::meanStdDev(valPixels1, mean1, stdDev1);
    cv::meanStdDev(valPixels0, mean0, stdDev0);

    double var1 = stdDev1[0] * stdDev1[0];
    double var0 = stdDev0[0] * stdDev0[0];

    return weight0 * var0 + weight1 * var1;
}

cv::Mat SelectThreshold(const cv::Mat& img) {
    cv::Mat resized;
    cv::resize(img, resized, cv::Size(10, 10), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    int maxVal = 255;
    std::vector<double> criterias;
    for (int th = 0; th <= maxVal; ++th) {
        criterias.push_back(CalculateCriteria(resized, th));
    }

    auto minElement = std::min_element(criterias.begin(), criterias.end());
    int bestThreshold = std::distance(criterias.begin(), minElement);

    cv::Mat binary;
    cv::threshold(img, binary, bestThreshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    return binary;
}
```

So this with resizing the image it seems works ok, but my question Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same results?
I am open to any suggestions, including optimizations to my current code or entirely new approaches that could offer better performance with the same result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of opportunities for improvement in the existing algorithm to cover them, but let's start with some low-hanging fruit. Why is `thresholdedIm` set to type `CV_64F` (a 64bit floating point number) when you only store zeros and ones in it? `CV_8UC1` is plenty for that, and takes 1/8 of the memory. But let's look further -- do we need a `1` explicitly, or would any non-zero number do, like the `255` that's used to signify "True" in the output of the comparison `im >= th`. So you can simply have `cv::Mat thresholdedIm = im >= th`.

Comment: That would mean that later on, you can directly use it as a mask, without need for yet another comparison pass in the `copyTo` -- `thresholdedIm == 1` would become just `thresholdedIm`, and `thresholdedIm == 0` could be replaced by simple inversion. | Weights for all 256 distinct threshold values could be calculated in single pass using a histogram.

Comment: And so could the rest of the stats in the first function be calculated just from the histogram data. With just the histogram calculation requiring a single pass through the input image, and the rest being done on a couple of 256 element arrays. That should make a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @DanMašek It sounds promising. I'm not sure I fully understand how to match it with my original code. if you could share some code it would help a lot. Did you mean something like this?
https://pastebin.com/SsEFGcDZ

Comment: Yeah I think you got the idea. It was interesting to measure the difference just that first comment made. My quick, sloppy  attempt at something is here: https://pastebin.com/E2Ue3FCk (the `dans2` variant). Could likely be made better, but I got other work to do now.

Comment: I got it now thank you so much! and I guess we start the loop from `histSize-1` here `for (int i(histSize); i > 0; --i)` otherwise histSize will out of bounds.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I suspected there was something iffy like that...

Comment: Thank you again this is a very good solution , and it was interesting to see.

Comment: read the Otsu paper. understand how it works. your code contains nothing sensitive to local patterns. there's no reason your approach should be slow, because it looks like you just tried to reimplement Otsu, except without the deeper math insights. to be blunt, that insight involves histograms and how to calculate mean and stddev on intervals of a histogram.

Comment: oh and that article you linked to... distrust the article and the author. the author claims in his article that Otsu is expensive. that is not so. Otsu is quite cheap. its cost is the histogram, plus one pass over the histogram doing a handful of arithmetic operations for each element.